# Does privilege level work in Packet Tracer's Switch-PT?

Tags: switch, packet-tracer

On Switch-PT in Packet Tracer, I'm trying to set a user with username `b` and secret `b`, with privilege level 5:

```
username b privilege 5 secret b
line console 0
login local
```

​

But when I do `show running-config`, the output for the username shows:

```
username b secret 5 $1$mERr$k9GHGlBNgfi56AfbMB8eT1
```

`show run` does not show that the user is assigned to a privilege level.

​

But when I login with username `b` and password `b`, I go straight into Privileged EXEC mode, and when I do `show privilege`, I get:

```
Current privilege level is 5
```

​

What's confusing is that `show running-config` does not show that the user is assigned to a privilege level whereas when I login with the username and password, it shows that I'm in privilege level 5.

​

But then I can still issue `configure terminal`, which I'm not sure why, because shouldn't users with privilege level less than 15 not be able to go into global configuration mode?

​

​

I tried running the same commands on a Router-PT, and my `show running-config` output is:

```
username b privilege 5 secret 5 $1$mERr$k9GHGlBNgfi56AfbMB8eT1
```

​

When I login with the username and password, I also go into Privileged EXEC mode, and `show privilege` still says:

```
Current privilege level is 5
```

, but I can not go into global config mode with `configure terminal`

​

It seems like configuring a privilege level for a user works fine on the router, but I'm confused on why isn't it working like the same on the switch.

Comment: Packet tracer is not actually IOS, nor does it have all the features. It is simply designed to get you through the CCNA exam. Most people here do not even have it because they are beyond that. You will find many missing features in PT that you will have on actual network equipment.

Comment: Why does `show privilege` show that the privilege level for `b` is 5 when `b` has all privileges?

Comment: You need to ask Cisco about that. PT is _not_ IOS. It is an application that is designed to get you through the CCNA. It has problems and limitations that IOS on actual devices does not have. You could always do a rack rental from one of the companies that provides that and connect to the racked equipment to use real IOS on real equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First- as many others PT is not IOS and many functions are either limited or do not work.

Second: Cisco defines two privilege levels by default (1 and 15) any non-default privilege level can be defined with privileges set.

You may be able to view the configuration by using the command “show run all” but I doubt the command works.

For more reading please check out https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960l/software/15-2_5_e/config-guide/b_1525e_consolidated_2960l_cg/b_1525e_consolidated_2960l_cg_chapter_0100001.pdf